# Android Button lighting border

Tags: android, button

Is it any way to light the borders of a button whilte pressing on it (you can see the effect when you place an ImageView and click on it). Needed to say, that i have a background on the buttone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two images and assign each of them to one button state. You should make a state list drawable: just create an xml file "button.xml" and place it in your res/drawable folder. The xml would look like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/buttonwithglow" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/buttonwithoutglow" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).